# javascript doesn't move element

Tags: javascript, css, input, css-transforms

I'm trying make a click-able box to disable the transform CSS. I'm trying to overwrite the CSS with javascript but it dosn't seem to be working. I would like them to simply move to left and down a bit after clicking on the `<a>`, where they would be if they just focused on the `<input>`.

```
.bigbox {
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius:      20px;
background-color:   blue;
color:  white;
padding-left: 15px;
}
#closebigbox {
padding:    10px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius:      20px;
background-color:   blue;
color:  white;
font-size:  8px;
width:  25px;
text-align: left;
background-color:   silver;
}
.bigbox_submit{
padding:    3px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius:      20px;
background-color:   blue;
color:  white;
font-size:  12px;
width:  25px;
text-align: left;
background-color:   silver;
}

.bigbox{ 
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
 } 
 .bigbox:focus { 
 background-color: #fc3; 
 -moz-transform: translate(125px,25px) scale(2); 
 }
```

---

```
<a href="javascript: document.getElementsByClassName('bigbox').style.position = 'relative'; document.getElementsByClassName('bigbox').style.left = '125px'; document.getElementsByClassName('bigbox').style.top = '25px';"  id="closebigbox" >Clear</a>

<form>
<input type="text"   class="bigbox" /><br/>
<input type="text"   class="bigbox" /><br/>
<input type="text"   class="bigbox" /><br/>
<a href="javascript:" class="bigbox_submit" >Submit</a>
</form>`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an Array so you'll need to loop through all of the elements and then apply the style:

```
var _elements = document.getElementsByClassName('bigbox');
for( var i = 0; i < _elements.length; i ++){
    _elements[i].style.position = 'relative'
    _elements[i].style.left= '125px'
    _elements[i].style.top= '25px'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this

```
$('Foo').animate({right:2000px}).delay(3000).animate({left: '0px' });
```